# Number theory problem RSA encryption

Tags: number-theory

Let p and q be distinct prime numbers and N = pq. G ={natural numbers less than pq that are relatively prime to pq}. if a and b are in G and k is a natural number, then prove

(1) G has (q-1)(p-1) elements.

(2) ab mod N is never 0.

(3) a^k mod N is never 0.

(4) ab mod N and a^k mod N are each elements of G.

I don't have clue how to do this problem. Anyone can help?

Comment: What do you know of number theory? These results are true for any $N$ with $G=\{\text{natural numbers relatively prime to }$N$\}$.

Comment: For instance, unique factorization can be used to show that if $ab$ and $N$ have a common factor, then (at least) one of $a$ or $b$ must have a common factor with $N$.

Comment: So because a and b are relatively prime to pq, ab cannot have common factor with pq right?

Comment: That's what you need to prove, yes. What you are allowed to use to prove that, if this is a problem set, depends on what you've covered so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Number of elements in $G = pq-|S|$,
   where 
   $$S = \{n \in N \mid\, p|n\, \text{ or }\, q|n\,,\, n\le pq\}$$

$|S|$ = number of multiples of $p$ which are $\le pq$ + number of multiples of $q$ which are $\le pq$ - number of multiples of $pq$ which are $\le pq$

Hence, $|S| = q +p -1$ and:

$$\begin{align}
|G| &= pq-(p+q-1)\\
&= pq-p-q+1\\
&= (q-1)(p-1)
\end{align}$$

2.
Let's assume $ab\equiv 0\pmod N$

Hence $N|ab$ and $pq|ab$, so that $p|ab\implies p|a \text{ or } p|b$ which contradicts the hypothesis that $\text{gcd}(a,pq) = 1$, $\text{gcd}(b,pq) = 1$

Hence, $ab\not\equiv 0\pmod N$

3.
Let's assume $ak\equiv 0\pmod N$

Hence, $N|ak$ and $pq|ak$, so that $p|ak$ and $q|ak$ $\implies$ $p|k$ and $q|k$ since $p$,$q$ are primes and $(a,p) = (a,q) = 1$ from hypothesis
=>
$pq|k$ since $p$,$q$ are primes, which contradicts the hypothesis that $(k,pq) = 1$
so that $ak\not\equiv 0 \pmod N$

4.
Let $ab \equiv m\pmod N$, $ak\equiv n\pmod N$
so that

$$0< m< N \text{ and } 0< n< N\tag{1}$$
which leads to
$ab = m+N\cdot m_{1}$ and $ak = n +N\cdot n_{1}$, for some integers

Let $d_1$ be a prime such that $d_{1}|m$, $d_{1}|N= pq$ so that $d_{1}|p$ or $d_{1}|q$, and $d_{1}|(m+N\cdot m_{1})= ab \implies d_{1}|a \text{ or } d_{1}|b$
the above statements contradicts the given hypothesis that 
$$(p,a) = (q,a) = (p,b) = (q,b) = 1$$
Hence $(m,N) = 1$ and $m$ belongs to $G$, i.e $ab \pmod N$ belongs to $G$,
similarly we can prove that $ak \pmod N$ belongs to $G$